# Ajax Table Result Is Not Calculating Sum Of Each Row's Price Column

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

[screenshot of sale page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pshI6.png)

Hi all. I have a sale page and another page which shows result according to the ajax post. I don't know if you can see the image but let me explain shortly.
The left side of the page shows the list of chosen products according to the product list on the right side which works with ajax post. I click on the right side product buttons and AJAX results bring the product to the left side list with the product name, quantity and price of the product. Everything works fine till this step. 
The problem is when i am choosing a product and it comes to the list of sale, i need to calculate the sum of this table's price column and show in another div-span out of this table. And i need to this live when i added a new product. And now it is showing the sum result of only first row in product list. Not calculating all.
 This is the script of sum:

```
<script>
var $form = $('#satis_bitir'),
$sumDisplay = $('#ara_toplam');

$form.on('keyup', 'input', function ()
{
var $summands = $form.find('#toplam_tutar');
var sum = 0;
$summands.each(function ()
{
    var value = Number($(this).val());
    if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
});

$sumDisplay.val(sum.toFixed(2)); 
});
</script>
```

So how can i calculate the whole list's price columns and show in another div->span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var updateCartAmount = function(){
    var $form = $('#satis_bitir'),
    $sumDisplay = $('#ara_toplam');

    var $summands = $form.find('.toplam_tutar');
    var sum = 0;
    $summands.each(function ()
    {
      var value = Number($(this).val());
      if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
    });
    $sumDisplay.val(sum.toFixed(2)); 
};


$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'your-url',
  data: {},
  success: function(){
      updateCartAmount(); //call your updateCartAmount here when ajax done
  }
});
```

Comment: Just re call updateCartAmount each time your send an ajax request to add any new product. No need to listen to keyboard keys any more.

Comment: Perfect.. Your codes are working just need to change updatedCartAmount(); to updateCartAmount(); :)) Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
#toplam_tutar
```

Try to use

```
.toplam_tutar
```

elements ids are unique means only the first div will be selected